# Unity rigidbody2d tilt issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to this and trying to learn how to use C# and unity. I'm currently trying to tilt my ship as you move back and forth on the x axis. however I'm getting a compiler error but cant see it? any help would be appreciated :)

The error is this:

> Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(28,62): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' to 'float'

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary {
    public float xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax;
}

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;
    public float tilt;
    public Boundary boundary;

    void FixedUpdate () {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector2 movement = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, moveVertical);
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = movement * speed;

        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().position = new Vector2 
            (
                Mathf.Clamp (this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
                Mathf.Clamp (this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().position.y, boundary.yMin, boundary.yMax)
            );

        //issue is on this line
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x * -tilt, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Quaternion.Euler` is returning a `UnityEngine.Quaternion`. But game `gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().rotation` is a float

Comment: can you suggest an alternative? I'm using unity 5, and to be fair I'm using a unity 4.3 tutorial to help. He uses the following code and it works: rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);    could it be that I'm using a rigidbody2D with 3D variables? Is there an alternative for 2D if so? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you're using probably uses `Rigidbody` (3D), while you're using `Rigidbody2D`.

[`Rigidbody2D.rotation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-rotation.html) is a `float` rotation around the Z axis.

[`Rigidbody.rotation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-rotation.html) is a `Quaternion` 3d rotation. Your code creates a `Quaternion`, which would work with `Rigidbody`, but you have a `Rigidbody2D`.

There are two ways to fix the error:

1. Use a 2d rotation, skipping creation of the `Quaternion`:

   ```
   var rigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   rigidbody2D.rotation = rigidbody2D.velocity.x * -tilt;
   ```
2. Change your code and Unity objects to use `Rigidbody`.

Comment: brilliant thank you this worked a charm :) edit: I used the first solution :)